# String value for arithmetic XPath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I found different result for following XSL transformation.

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:variable name="p1" select="a/@p1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="p2" select="a/@p2"/>
        <xsl:variable name="p3" select="a/@p3"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$p1+$p2*$p3"/><br />
        <xsl:value-of select="$p2*$p3+$p1"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<test>
    <a p1="1458569700" p2="60" p3="60"/>
</test>
```

libxslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
1458573300<br/>1458573300
```

Some kind of Java library (http://xslttest.appspot.com):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>1.4585733E9<br/>1.4585733E9
```

Who is correct and why (reference to specification would be great)?

Comment: Can you check the `system-property('xsl:version')` and `xsl:vendor`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen for Java library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both results are "correct" mathematically. In terms of standards, XSLT 1.0 does not allow scientific notation, but XSLT 2.0 does.

**XPath 1.0:**

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#exprlex
production [30]

**XPath 2.0**:

> The rules for converting numbers to strings have changed. These may
>   affect the way numbers are displayed in the output of a stylesheet.
>   For numbers whose absolute value is in the range 1E-6 to 1E+6, the
>   result should be the same, but outside this range, scientific format
>   is used for non-integral xs:float and xs:double values.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-incompat-in-true-mode

Comment: Can we say that in XSLT 1.0 we always have integer representation for double value when we need string?

Comment: There is no double in XSLT 1.0. I have added a reference to the lexical structure of a number in XSLT 1.0 . See also https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string regarding conversion of number to string.